# Using two conditions inside Events in Matlab ODE

Tags: matlab, events, differential-equations

I have a ODE `Event` as

```
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-11,'Events',@eventfunction);
    [time,values] = ode45(@Eq,time,x0,options);

function [value, isterminal,direction]=eventfunction(~,y)
value=y(1)+y(2)-1;
isterminal=1;
direction=0;
end
```

I want to change this condition inside `eventfunction` so that the event will be triggered when `y(1)+y(2)` falls below 1 OR moves above 10^5.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify vectors for value, isterminal, and direction.

```
value = [y(1)+y(2)-1, y(1)+y(2)-1e5];
isterminal = [1, 1];
direction = [0, 0];
```

Note that you can use direction = [], it functions the same as providing direction = zeros(1,length(value)).